# How to add a class to the current li or image?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, easyslider

I want to add a class on the current `li` or `image`, but I can not see any options for that.

Anyone knows how?

This is how I am calling it:

```
$(".slider-view").easySlider({
        auto: true,
        continuous: true,
        speed: 1000,
        pause: 5000
});
```

Comment: You can add class to any li (every slideshow item actually) in css, i am not sure that targeting current have sense in this case? One item is visible, rest aren't, right?

Comment: @OliveraKovacevic Were you able to find out a solution in the end? :o

Comment: Not per se, but I found a workaround using a certain slider and a function I found on SO.

Answer (score 1):

To add class to current item in jquery you can use following code :

```
$(this).addClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.addClass()`

Try this:

```
$('li').addClass('slider-view');
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Yea but how to add it to the CURRENT one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
$(".slider-view").easySlider({
        auto: true,
        continuous: true,
        speed: 1000,
        pause: 5000
}).addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for the easySlider plugin](http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/), there is no option to add a custom class to the current item. With the slider active, you should inspect your HTML (using your browser's developer tools), and see what class the plugin adds to the current item.

You can then add your custom class like this:

```
// Replace .easySliderClassName with the active class you find in the HTML
$(".easySliderClassName").addClass('.your-class');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a pretty small change to the source code to add this into the `easySlider` plugin. Having looked at it, it *really* is a pretty simple/stripped bare Plugin, there's far more available out there that offer common things such as callbacks etc.

Although, within the Plugin's `adjust()` method add:

```
$("ul li", obj).removeClass('current-slide').eq(t+1).addClass('current-slide');
```

For it to sit like below at the end of the adjust function, this'll remove any `.current-slide` class before the next slide is called, then reapplied.

```
function adjust(){

     clickable = true;

     /** 
      *  Where `t` is the current slide index. 
      *  and obj refers to $(this) (The .easySlider ojb)
     **/
     $("ul li", obj).removeClass('current-slide')
                    .eq(t+1)
                    .addClass('current-slide');

     if(options.numeric) 
          setCurrent(t);
};
```

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/864DZ/